# Book reference in BibTeX does not show all fields

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have this entry in the bib file:

```
@book{griepenkerl2002,
  title="Intensity distribution for diffraction by a slit and Intensity pattern for diffraction by a grating",
  author="Griepenkerl, Kordt",
  year="2002",
  editor="In: Handbook of physics. John W Harris; Walter Benenson; Horst Stöcker; Holger Lutz",
  publisher="Springer"
}
```

and no matter how I twist it, it does not show the editor name in the list of references, which is very important. I just get

[image]

At the end of the documentI have:

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt} 
\bibliography{bib}
```

Any ideas how I can show the full information?

Thanks

Comment: the fields use depend on the style you specify, about which you have given no information. Presumably you are using biblatex not bibtex from your tag

Comment: I use the following end on the document
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bib}

Comment: so you are _not_ using biblatex, but bibtex, why the biblatex tag? That is the main part of your question, you should add it to your questio as a small example doc showing the style used

Comment: Because these are details that are completely unknown to me.

Comment: And there is why we always ask for a minimal example so we know **exactly** what you are doing.

Comment: It is given in the post

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the `@incollection` entry type, not the `@book` entry type. And, while you're at it, do please provide suitable `chapter` and `pages` fields for this entry as well.

```
@book{griepenkerl2002,
  title     = "Intensity distribution for diffraction by a slit and 
               Intensity pattern for diffraction by a grating",
  author    = "Griepenkerl, Kordt",
  year      = 2002,
  booktitle = "Handbook of Physics",
  editor    = "Walter Benenson and John W. Harris and Horst Stöcker 
               and Holger Lutz",
  publisher = "Springer",
  address   = "New York",
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks Mico!    It worked